# React Js - How to change a color in checkbox when it is checked?

Tags: css, reactjs

Howto change the color in the  checkbox when it is checked?
When my checkbox is checked, it has this color: [image]

But i want to change to red.

How i can do that?

```
  <input
        type="checkbox"
        disabled={isDisabled}
        defaultChecked={checked}
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accent-color` css property:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09m52duf/)

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" />
```

Keep the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=accent-color) in mind when using this.